# iPython parallel pushing every objects is messy

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, ipython-parallel

I love iPython notebook but on parallel processing with ipyparallel, pushing every local objects into engine with `dview.push(dict(...))` seems not effective way. Do you have any effective alternatives to do that?

I usually do like:

```
from IPython import parallel

rc = parallel.Client()
dview = rc[:]
dview.push(dict(x1=x1, x2=x2, ...., x100=x100)) # => I'd like to avoid this!!
res = dview.map_async(run_once, range(5))
map_result = res.get()
rc.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPython Parallel doesn't resolve closures before sending functions by default. That means that when you send `run_once` to the engine, and the body of `run_once` looks for `x1`, it's going to look for `x1` on the engine, instead of carrying with it a copy of `x1` on your client. This can be useful because it lets you do [SPMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPMD) operations by changing what `x1` means on each engine. For instance, this snippet relies on `rank` having a different value on each engine in order to work properly:

```
dview.scatter('rank', rc.ids, flatten=True)

def mul_by_rank(x):
    return x * rank

dview.map_sync(mul_by_rank, range(len(rc)))
```

If you do want to resolve closures when you send a function (that is, implicitly send x1, x2 along with run_once), you can use other serialization libraries which do this. One version of this is `cloudpickle`, which you can enable with `dview.use_cloudpickle()` (you must have installed cloudpickle first). If you do this, then the local variables that `run_once` relies on should be sent along with `run_once`:

```
dview.use_cloudpickle()
dview.map_sync(run_once, range(5))
```

Comment: Thanks. I really want to know `cloud_pickle`!